# Why does this phantomjs code return null and the document title?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am trying to learn PhantomJS. I would appreciate if you can help me understand why the code below gives me an error(shown below) and help me fix the error. I am trying to execute some javascript on a page using phantomjs. The code lines in the evaluate function work well when I enter them in Chrome console, i.e., they give the expected result (document.title).

Thank you.

**PhantomJS Code**

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

var url = 'http://www.google.com';

page.open(url, function(status) {


    var title = page.evaluate(function(query) {
        document.querySelector('input[name=q]').setAttribute('value', query);

        document.querySelector('input[name="btnK"]').click();

        return document.title;
    }, 'phantomJS');

    console.log(title);

    phantom.exit()
})
```

**Error**

```
TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'document.querySelector('input[name="btnK"]').click')

  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():4
  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():7
  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():7
null
```

**Edit 1: In response to Andrew's answer**

Andrew, it is strange but on my computer, the button is an input element. The following screenshot shows the result on my computer.

[image]

**Edit 2: click event unreliable**

Sometimes, the following click event works, sometimes it does not.

```
document.querySelector('input[name="btnK"]')
```

Not clear to me what is happening.

**About the answer**

For future readers, in addition to the answer, the gist by Artjom B. is helpful in understanding what is happening. However, for a more robust solution, I think something like the waitfor.js example will have to be used (as suggested in the answer). I hope it is okay to copy and paste Artjom B.'s gist here. While the gist below works (with form submit); it is still not clear to me why it does not work if I try to simulate the click button on the input. If anyone can clarify that, it would be great.

```
// Gist by Artjom B.
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = 'http://www.google.com';
page.open(url, function(status) {
    var query = 'phantomJS';
    page.evaluate(function(query) {
        document.querySelector('input[name=q]').value = query;
        document.querySelector('form[action="/search"]').submit();
    }, query);
    setTimeout(function(){
        var title = page.evaluate(function() {
            return document.title;
        });
        console.log(title);
        phantom.exit();
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Google might deliver different pages to different clients, so it might be "input" for you browser, but "button" for the phantomjs. Try log the document.body, and check what really is there.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. It is input but with name="btnG". This time it did not give an error. So that part worked. However, it did not click the button either. The page title it returned was "Google" the same before the search term was submitted.

Comment: That makes sense. click will cause a navigation, and it takes time. To get the new title, wait some time, e.g. 3s, or listen for the page load event like this: page.onLoadFinished = function(){ ..evaluate.. }. Also check casperjs, it's built on Phantomjs, but easier to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google uses a form for submitting its queries.  It's also highly likely that google has changed the prototype methods for their search buttons, so it's not really the best site to test web scraping.

The easiest way to do this is to actually perform a form submit, which slightly tweaks your example.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = 'http://www.google.com';
page.open(url, function(status) {
    var query = 'phantomJS';
    var title = page.evaluate(function(query) {
        document.querySelector('input[name=q]').value = query;
        document.querySelector('form[action="/search"]').submit();
        return document.title
    }, query);
console.log(title);
phantom.exit();
});
```

Note that you will likely need to consider that the response is async from this call, so getting the title directly will likely result in an undefined error (you need to account for the time it takes for the page to load before looking up data; you can review this in their [waitfor.js](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js) example).

Comment: You're right, there is no way you can click that button with phantomjs (or casperjs). You might want to wait a little before returning the title. See this [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cb33e8173c0c56e85597).

Comment: Your gist worked great. Thank you. However, the same setTimeOut does not work with the button click. Why is a form submit required? Does clicking the button not submit the form?

Comment: @Curious2learn Generally a click would submit the form, but I think that google uses some techniques to detect a client and throw stones in the way. It is really hard to navigate google sites using phantomjs/casperjs. Almost all other sites behave correctly. There are still problems with assumptions on how phantomjs/casperjs work otherwise there wouldn't be so many questions on SO.

Comment: Thank you Artjom. As you and rknuu said, I should not try things on Google when learning webscraping and phantomJS.

Answer (score 3):

You can open google.com and try document.querySelector('input[name="btnK"]') in the console, it's null.
[image: google input]

Actully try replace input with button:

```
document.querySelector('button[name="btnK"]')
```

[image: google search button]

Comment: please see my response above as Edit 1.